# Can I can return json list from HttpClientResponse

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to connect with our server using dart and flutter. I get an error in certificate server, I get the code and I get response exactly, but the problem is the response keeps coming back as a string. I want it as a list to loop through it.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.badCertificateCallback =((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);
String url ='https://xxx';
//Map map = { "email" : "email" , "password" : "password"};
HttpClientRequest request = await client.getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
//request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');
//request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(map)));
HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
String reply = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
print(reply);
```

I have simple code to get a JSON response as a list. The problem is our server is using https and nginx to take all request to the correct port. Previous code worked but I need to respond with a list.

simple code is :

```
String apiURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

 http.Response response = await http.get(apiURL);

return json.decode(response.body);
```

Comment: Do you need List<User> which is returned by the link your posted

Answer (score -1):

You won't get a list. You would get flat json which you would need to process. Processing can be done using simple script using powershell.